# swiftui transition not work on extracted view

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

I just build a small pop up with .spring() animation that I want to use later in my app, but the back transition is not smooth. It simply disappear from the hierarchy. So here is my code:

```
struct TestPopUp: View {


@State var screen: Bool = false

var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            VStack {
                Button("Click") {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        screen.toggle()
                    }
                   
                }
                .font(.largeTitle)

                if screen {
                    NewScreen(screen: $screen)
                        .padding(.top, 300)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                }
}

struct NewScreen: View {
    
    @Binding var screen: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Color.black
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            Button {
                screen.toggle()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "xmark")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding(20)
            }

            
        }
    }
}
```

[Transition popup](https://easyupload.io/0bvqxm)

As you can see in the video, the view disappears. But I want the same transition backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to animate the transition both ways, in and out. Therefore, `NewScreen` becomes:

```
struct NewScreen: View {
    
    @Binding var screen: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Color.black
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            Button {
                withAnimation(.spring()) { // Animate here!
                    screen.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "xmark")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding(20)
            }
        }
    }
}
```